# XenServer not detecting whole RAM (Dom0 and DomU 32-bit issue)

Tags: memory, xenserver, hypervisor, 32-bit, dom0

Well, somewhere I has read that my machine has a problem reading all the RAM because of the 32-bit limitation:

http://xenserver.org/blog/entry/the-reality-of-a-64-bit-dom0.html

[image]

I don't underestand anything, can somebody explain what this means?

http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/265801-xenserver-detected-just-3319mb-ram-howto-set-more/

[image]

My problem here is that I have also an Asrock MB and I don't know if the problem is here, or is with my instalation:

[image]

Somewhere, outside my home, I have also installed XenServer with the same ISO and 4GB and everything is working fine.

But here not, I don't know exactly if I have to patch something... Because in the first image the Xen Project Hypervision redirects me to: http://xenproject.org/developers/teams/hypervisor.html

That means that If I install this packet I will fix this?

Can somebody explain all this to me?

Please, don't downvote me, I don't know if the things I'm asking is in the correct way, I didn't talk of any of this things by myself because I don't understand anything, so any help is welcome.

**EDIT:**

There are some posts I have also readed that I didn't understand:

https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Software_Overview

https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Dom0_Kernels_for_Xen

Can somebody tell clearly what I need to do, or to know to solver this issue?

By the moment I understand that XenServers runs on 64-bit (I don't have any 32-bit option, but I can't prove that this is really 64-bit), but that part that controls the hardware is in 32-bits, how this is possible? Can I fix this? Why in my other machine using the same ISO I don't have problems? That means that I have a problem with my hardware, is there any compatibility issue?

**EDIT2:**

[image]

Intel (R) virtualization is enabled...  So, the only thing, that you have to do is tell me to check things by the moment.

But there is something that was unexpected:

[image]

When the BIOS is loading, it tell me that it has 3319MB, that I think is RAM, and XenServer only can use 3318MB... So, can I imagine that the BIOS detect the two modules, but, It only uses 3318MB, actually the problem is not in XenServer, the real problem is with the hardware???

**Thanks!**

Comment: In big, you have more than 4gb of ram in the server, the motherboard only see 4gb, and xenserver dont want to install ?

Comment: Nope, I have 4096MB of RAM physically installed, but XenServer only uses 3318MB, and I want to know if there is any apparently cause of this, and how can I solve this. Thanks @yagmoth555

Comment: is virtualisation enabled in the motherboard ? see there for maybe where the setting is; http://forum.asrock.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=671&title=inclusion-virtualization-in-bios

Comment: Mmmm... I hadn't check that, but If this relevant, and also, if it was disabled, I couldn't run any VM, but actually I could. So, where is the problem!!? :/ thanks anyway, I will check that.

Comment: I just edited my post, there is something interesting...

Comment: integrated video card surellythen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved myself the problem.

It was problem of the BIOS, because I bought two modules of 2GB of DDR2 and I had to activate the Memory Remap option.